# Get FCM remote notification when app is closed completely iOS

Tags: ios, notifications, swift2, apple-push-notifications, remote-notifications

I am using FCM to send notifications from my own server to iOS Devices. I get notifications successfully when app is in foreground or minimized. But when I close the app completely , even from background, I don't get any notification. But when I reopen the app I get all the notifications that I send earlier ? How can I change this ?

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I'm registering for notifications.
In `didReceiveRemoteNotification` fetching notification and scheduling local notification.

Comment: Hi, I have the similar issue. Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: Not really. I got the same issue in android too

Answer (score 0):

Add this line

```
Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
```

after

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
```